# VIM vertical resize to a specific direction

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remap the regular vim shortcut Ctrl-W+< and Ctrl-W+> to resize the current active pane to the specified direction ('<' for left and '>' for right) but unfortunately I couldn't find a command which does that, only a command which increases/decreases the pane size by the specified amount, which is not what I need.

this is currently what I have:

```
nnoremap <C-w>> :vertical res +5<CR>
nnoremap <C-w>< :vertical res -5<CR>
```

But this increases the current window size by 5 columns no matter if I'm in the right pane or the left pane, which is not very intuitive.

Is there a command which resizes current window to left or right (similiar to Tmux way of doing those things)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it based on the window number:

```
au! WinEnter * call SetWinAdjust()

fun! SetWinAdjust()
   if winnr() > 1
      nnoremap <C-w>> <C-w><
      nnoremap <C-w>< <C-w>>
   else
      nnoremap <C-w>> <C-w>>
      nnoremap <C-w>< <C-w><
   endif
endfun
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't quite figure out how does this solve my problem... On the same logic I could've remapped
    `nnoremap <C-w>> :vertical res +5<CR>` and
    `nnoremap <C-w>< :vertical res -5<CR>`

to the opposite `-5` and `5` respectively...

But I need some way to do this dynamically, since when my current pane is on the left side, I need `>` to increase it's size and when i'm on the right side I want `<` to increase it's size (and decide on some other behaviour if there are more than 2 vertical panes)

Comment: @MikeyS. Sorry about that. I misunderstood the question. I've provided a different solution.

Comment: Your solution is great, but in case of 3 windows, the middle window resizing is unintuitive (I expected that when I use <C-w>> in the middle window, it will expend that window to the right, on the expense of the righter window, but the other occured). replacing the `winnr() > 1` with `winnr() == winnr('$')` fixes this problem. Thanks a lot!